# Solving $Ax = b$ for non-negative $x$ given boolean matrix $A$ and non-negative $b$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, computational-complexity, integer-programming

I am trying to solve $Ax = b$ with the following properties:

- $A$ is a boolean (aka. logical, binary) matrix, i.e., each entry in $A$ is either $0$ or $1$
- $A$ is of size $m \times n$ where $m \ll n$
- Each entry in $b$ is a non-negative integer
- Each entry in $x$ should be a non-negative integer
- It is known that such a $x$ exists

I am able to solve it as an **integer linear program** using standard LP solvers but how to solve it with a matrix based approach? Given the special properties of the problem, I believe there definitely would be some nice matrix based approach.

We may also relax $x$ to have non-negative real numbers and/or settle for an approximate solution if getting an exact solution in not easy.

Comment: Are you looking for something different than regular old Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @wgrenard Gaussian elimination doesn't ensure non-negative x

Comment: The fact that you talk about linear programming makes me wonder if you are interested in the complexity theory aspects of this problem. If so, you should state that fact explicitly and probably should post it on cs theory stack exchange.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Thanks for pointing! I added the #computational-complexity tag. I guess only mathematicians can exploit the special structure of this problem and comeup with maybe a closed-form expression for x

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, answers requiring pseudocode (which this is, if GE isn't fast enough) aren't "math-y enough" for here. CS theory stack exchange is your best best.

Comment: You should also indicate what time complexity bounds you are hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to the Min/Max Flow problem and using the [Network Simplex Method](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/miketodd/or630/lec18.pdf) to solve the integer model of the following form:

$$\min z = \sum_{(i,j)\in E}c_{(i,j)}x_{(i,j)}$$
$$\text{Subject to:}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$$
$$\sum_{(i,j)\in E} x_{(i,j)} -\sum_{(i,j)\in E}x_{(i,j)}=b_m\quad\forall m\in{1, 2,\ldots,m}$$
$$0\le x_{(i,j)} \le u_{(i,j)}\quad\forall (i,j)\in E$$
$$x_{(i,j)}\in\mathbb{Z}^+\quad\forall (i,j)\in E$$

where $E$ denotes the set of all arcs in a graph, $x_{(i,j)}$ is the decision variable denoting the number of resources go from which node to another via arc $(i,j)$, and $u_{(i,j)}$ is the upper bounds of each decision variable. Given the notion that the entire coefficient matrix of $A$ is binary (there exists a connection from one node to another), and that arcs can only have non-negative, integer flows, then solving the mentioned problem via the Network Simplex method could be done via a matrix approach that takes advantage of the behaviors and sparcities of the constraint matrix since it heavily relies on all the properties you've mentioned.

However, since it's a rather large algorithm in terms of background (substantially more than this thread), here are some resources for better understanding how to use it in both its [matrix form](http://math.ucdenver.edu/%7Esborgwardt/wiki/index.php/Exploring_the_Network_Simplex_Method) and [graphically](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/pstuckey/COMP90046/lec/s4_networkflow.pdf).